# How to remove objects from R environment containg umlauts in their names?

Tags: r

I would like to remove specific objects in my R workspace that contain umlauts (ä, ö, ü). I tried different things to get rid of these objects (values in that case) but none of this worked. Also, bear in mind that I would like to *keep* all functions in my workspace (just as a further condition).

```
Grüne <- 1
```

First try:

```
rm(Grüne)

Warning message:
In rm("Grüne") : object 'Grüne' not found
```

Second try:

```
rm(list = setdiff(ls(all.names=T), lsf.str(all.names=T))) # To remove everything except functions

# The object "Grüne" is still present in the workspace.
```

Third try:

```
rm("Gr\u00FCne") # Unicode nomralization...?

Warning message:
In rm("Grüne") : object 'Grüne' not found
```

Comment: As does `rm(\`Grüne\`)` with backticks. What about `rm(list=ls(pattern="^Gr.ne"))` where you are deleting anything matching the pattern `Gr<any character>ne`? Maybe the `ü` is not actually `ü`.

Comment: Oh wow, I just found out that the only reason "Grüne" was still there was because the workspace/ environment had not automatically been reloaded. Usually the objects disappear from the list instantly without having to reload the environment, no? So I'm still wondering whether that had something to do with the umlauts...